# Does GCP Support GRE over UDP for monitoring in Google Cloud

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

I need to find out if Google Cloud supports Generic Routing Encapsulation, or GRE over UDP. This would be used for monitoring.

I've been able to confirm that GRE is available on Google Cloud from the documentation.

> VPC networks support GRE traffic, including traffic on Cloud VPN and
> Cloud Interconnect. VPC networks do not support GRE for Cloud NAT or
> for forwarding rules for load balancing and protocol forwarding.
> Support for GRE allows you to terminate GRE traffic on a VM from the
> internet (external IP address) and Cloud VPN or Cloud Interconnect
> (internal IP address). The decapsulated traffic can then be forwarded
> to a reachable destination. GRE enables you to use services such as
> Secure Access Service Edge (SASE) and SD-WAN.

This would be used for monitoring Kubernetes (K8s) clusters in Google Cloud (GKE) and Google Compute Engine (GCE).

But I have not been able to confirm if it will work over UDP. Can anyone point to any documentation saying that GRE over UDP works?

Comment: The transport layer for GRE is UDP. GRE does not run over UDP unless you are tunneling inside a tunnel. Google Cloud supports GRE over IP as its own protocol (same level as ICMP, UDP, TCP, etc). Supported services are Compute Engine VMs, Cloud VPN, and Cloud Interconnect. Edit your question with details on the Google services that you are using and what you are configuring (Windows VPN, custom tunneling application, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question to include that we would be monitoring GKE and GCE on GCP.

Comment: Your edit does not provide useful information. Why would you try to use GRE to monitor Kubernetes or Compute Engine? Unless you are using a custom monitoring application that you want to secure via a VPN tunnel, Google Cloud Monitoring has its own API to use. Edit your question with a specific configuration and problem and not generalization like monitoring something.

Comment: I don't know what monitoring system the client is using to moniotor Kubernetes and GCE. I will have to see if I can find out and edit the question.

Comment: If you do not know which monitoring system, why are you asking about GRE? I am not aware of any monitoring system that depends upon GRE.

Comment: The client sent a list of questions that I need to answer for them. This was one of the questions that they had. I am not aware of any monitoring system that usess GRE either. They apparently have some monitoring system that uses GRE and they want to know how it can integrate with GCP.

Comment: Setting up GRE tunnels to Compute Engine is no problem. However, I have not attempted this with Kubernetes. I think the only GRE approach is to set up GRE to Compute Engine and then normal VPC networking to Kubernetes. Note: when you start forwarding packets between networks and over tunnels, exact details are required. Recommendation: I would not use GRE unless that is already designed in. Google Cloud VPN provides more features, easier integration, etc.